# SharePoint Search Web Parts in the ONET

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site def for Search Server Express that includes a custom search aspx.  I can deploy the site and add web parts to this page and it all works quite nicely thank you.

I now want to have the web parts automatically added to the search page so I exported the web part xml and inserted this into the onet.  Ive followed instructions where I can find them but of course, it's broken.  I have errors like:  "An unexpected error has occurred" for the search pager, "Unable to display this Web Part" for the core results and the search summary works but does not show all the query properties in the web part editor.

Ive compared the search page using SPD and the onet with the Search Centre template and I cant see what is wrong.  I'm lost.

Anyone got a sample or suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have search properties specified in the search results webpart, this error will occur if the property is not also specified as a search property for your site.  Try checking those first.

Also check the logs for more specific errors. They can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is the problem.  The logs have:

Error importing WebPart. Assembly  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, TypeName. Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.FederatedResultsWebPart  

- which is not particularly informative :(